# Maven not found while using Gitlab-ci-multi-runner

Tags: java, maven, raspbian, gitlab-ci-runner

I've been trying to set up GitLab-CI to build Maven Java projects in Raspbian, but whenever It tries to run the build script it fails because it can't find Maven. I used [this](http://pragma-int.blogspot.com.es/2015/11/gitlab-ci-and-maven.html) guide to install the runner.

Build trace:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.10.4 (b32125f)
WARNING: image is not supported by selected executor and shell
Using Shell executor...
Running on raspberrypi...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/f09314a8/0/RBian/TestProject'...
Checking out 54d2e140 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ mvn clean package
bash: line 22: mvn: command not found
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8

build:
  script: "mvn clean package"
  artifacts:
    name: "TestProject"
    paths:
    - "target/*.jar"
```

Does anyone know what causes this?

EDIT: Modifying /etc/default to add $MAVEN_HOME/bin to $PATH did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ***MAVEN_HOME*** path into ***config.toml*** environment field.

```
environment = ["MAVEN_HOME=/path/to/maven"]
```